# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a simple spring boot starter project.
I am getting following error while running the project in STS eclipse tool. Here's the full stack trace that I got from terminal. I tried various solutions from other posts, but It didn't work for me.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-07-26 13:29:15.193  INFO 85725 --- [           main] com.ibm.starterProject.DemoClass         : Starting DemoClass on Akash.local with PID 85725 (/Users/Akash/Documents/workspace_Microservices/starterProject/target/classes started by Akash in /Users/Akash/Documents/workspace_Microservices/starterProject)
2017-07-26 13:29:15.197  INFO 85725 --- [           main] com.ibm.starterProject.DemoClass         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-26 13:29:15.291  INFO 85725 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3444d69d: startup date [Wed Jul 26 13:29:15 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-26 13:29:17.169  INFO 85725 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-07-26 13:29:17.183  INFO 85725 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-07-26 13:29:17.185  INFO 85725 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-07-26 13:29:17.343  INFO 85725 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-07-26 13:29:17.343  INFO 85725 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2056 ms
2017-07-26 13:29:17.521  INFO 85725 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-07-26 13:29:17.525  INFO 85725 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-26 13:29:17.525  INFO 85725 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-26 13:29:17.525  INFO 85725 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-26 13:29:17.525  INFO 85725 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-26 13:29:18.578  INFO 85725 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-07-26 13:29:18.597  WARN 85725 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
2017-07-26 13:29:18.601  INFO 85725 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-07-26 13:29:18.615  INFO 85725 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-07-26 13:29:18.625 ERROR 85725 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.starterProject.DemoClass.main(DemoClass.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554) ~[jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar:3.3.1.Final]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529) ~[jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar:3.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516) ~[jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar:3.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:28) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:24) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<clinit>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
  <artifactId>starterProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>new Project</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>


  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId> 
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Please help how I will be able to resolve this. Thanks for help.

Comment: purge your local repository to get a fresh copy of the jars. Probably a borked jar. Do `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` then rebuild.

Comment: @M.Deinum It worked. Thanks!!